# О способе образования слова "пригорюниться"

Tags: словообразование, глаголы, суффиксы, приставки

Требуется **креативное** решение.

В Сети можно найти мнение, что  для этого глагола  используется **префиксально-постфиксальный** способ образования. А почему не **префиксальный** с помощью приставки ПРИ?
Я сначала именно так считала по **образцу** (словообразовательной модели): ***лечь — прилечь***, но теперь сомневаюсь.

Comment: _**«В Сети можно найти мнение, что для этого глагола используется префиксально-постфиксальный способ образования._»** === Ссылку можете дать, где  Вы смогли увидеть такое мнение? У меня, к сожалению не получилось этого сделать

Comment: Попробуйте увидеть здесь  https://slova-razbor.ru/морфемный/пригорюниться

Comment: М-да…  Лучше этим сайтом пока не пользоваться, ведь сами же его разработчики предупреждают: _«Примите во внимание: разбор слова "пригорюниться" по составу определён по специальному алгоритму с минимальным участием человека и **может быть неточным**»_.

Comment: На этом сайте чуть ниже приведен ещё один способ образования слова _пригорюниться_:  _«Способ образования слова: **сложный**»_ ❓

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первая, можно сказать интуитивная, мысль: "Конечно префиксальный".
**Это не ответ, а мои рассуждения**.
Помню из вопросов-ответов-обсуждений-споров, что есть языковед Тихонов, и, как я понял, он часто не выделяет все "микроморфемы" при разборе слова.
Меня зацепил вопрос, и я полез в Викисловарь. (Многие скажут, это ненадежно. Но сейчас не об этом.)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здесь у Тихонова (насколько можно верить Викисловарю) представлены все значимые части слова. С полным разбором я полностью согласен, но здесь отсутствует сам термин из словообразования.
Смотрю [**горюниться**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F), а там написано вот так: Корень: --.
Ну, думаю, тем лучше.
Когда перешел по ссылке из комментария, удивился, насколько всё там непонятно для меня, дошел до конца... и тоже хотел написать о предупреждении самих авторов, как это сделал участник Слава. Но самое интересное, что заголовочный их вариант почти соответствует моему представлению об образовании слов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Только они взяли в расчет и постфиксы, которые **уже есть** в слове-исходнике, поэтому, видимо, и определили наше слово в префиксально-постфиксальную корзину.
А я не беру во внимание постфиксы, потому что рассуждаю так: есть слово "горюниться" (это оно образовалось постфиксально), к слову-единице добавилась приставка – появилась новая единица "пригорюниться".

**Ответ:** для меня это **префиксальный** способ образования слова.

Comment: Александр, спасибо большое за ответ. Вероятно, мне придется с вами согласиться и я приму ваш ответ,  но хотелось бы задать доп. вопросы.  Мне очень интересно, как вы креативно на них ответите) Вопросов по этому слову у меня много. Может, поиграем в ролевую игру: я как будто журналист, а вы это вы. Я чуть позже запишу  вопросы отдельно, а вы выскажете свое мнение  по любым из них. Вопросы мне надо предварительно обдумать, так что получится не сразу.

Comment: Хорошо. Только буду занят другим делом, поэтому могу отвечать не сразу.

Comment: Разумеется,  да и у меня вопросы еще не готовы. Это так, в проекте)  Поэтому я принимаю ваш ответ, но надеюсь на будущий разговор, если вопросы покажутся вам интересными.

Comment: Пока придумала только один вопрос, но он получился длинный. Задам его на форуме, а вы уделите ему внимание, пжста, если будет время))

Comment: Да... вопросик не просто длинный, а насыщенный. Я думал, будем играть в "да, нет, не знаю, правда, неправда, упс". :)

Comment: В другой раз придумаю "да – нет", ладно?  А на эти отвечайте по зову души, по велению сердца,  если что понравится.  Там много разных вопросиков в двух темах)  Это у меня как бы конференция, тоже такая креативная игра.

Comment: Но у меня есть к вам такой вопрос.  Вам  очень нравится слово "насмотренность". В словаре его нет, поэтому нет и правильного морфемного разбора. А как бы вы разобрали это слово? Будете выделять "микроморфемы" или нет? Как бы поступил Тихонов?